# How does Dr. Doofenshmirtz know Perry's name?

Tags: character, phineas-and-ferb

Dr. Doofenshmirtz from *Phineas and Ferb* obviously knows Perry's name; it's even in his catchphrase ("Curse you, Perry the Platypus!"). But Perry doesn't speak or anything.

How does Dr. Doofenshmirtz know Perry's name?

Comment: I think he got a visiting card with his name

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the [Phineas & Ferb wiki](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Cheers_for_Fears) comes the following quote by Doofenschmirtz from the season 4 episode *Chears for Fears*:

> **Dr. Doofenshmirtz:** Alright, so what are you afraid of, where is it?
>
> (*looks around*)
>
> What the hay? Nothing?
>
> (*A **business card** slips through the ropes. Doof takes the card and reads it.*)
>
> "**Perry the Platypus: O.W.C.A. agent** - Fearless." Huh. That figures. I guess you'll just hafta...hang around! Ha ha ha! Oh, wait, this one's better: I'll just leave you here because you're all tied up! Ha ha ha! W-W-Wait, one last one, you're gonna love it: See ya later because it isn't my tail that's upside down!
>
> (*No response.*)
>
> No? No no, I shoulda stuck with the first two, you're right.

So it is clear that Perry (and presumably every O.W.C.A agent) carries a business card (just as @AnkitSharma suggested in his comment) and we can also assume that once upon an earlier meeting Perry showed that card to Doofenshmirtz.

Comment: Then why didn't the Dr. know Perry is fearless?

Comment: @jpmc26 I don't know, maybe he carries multiple different business cards that say different things in addition to his name and organisation.

Comment: @jpmc26 Doof was never the most "with it" person. He probably just forgot.

Answer (score 3):

A second possibility from a theoretical point of view. The show hinges so much on surreality and breaking standard animation conventions. For example most of the music on the show has been shown to be diegetic. (Intentional and of origin within the story). Example: Doofenshmirtz' theme being recorded by him.

As a result it is possible that Perry's theme is heard by Doof anytime Perry shows up.

This is just a thrown out theory because to be honest... it's P&F where the answer "Doof, are you one of those people who's always just known Perry's name" would be "Yes, Yes I am."

Comment: I figured it was gonna get minused. Just tried to come up with a fun theory as a fan of the show.